# How to get opposite angle quaternion

Tags: quaternions

I am calculating the quaternion rotation between 2 quaternions.

I know that Q1 = r x Q2, so I thought that r = Q1 x Q2*
(asterisk means conjugate)

This however seems to give me the opposite of the angle I need.

ex.  If Q1 and Q2 are Pi/2 off, I will get a quaternion of -Pi/2.  How can I get the correct angle I need?

Example:
I am looking 45 degrees left from forward.  I am moving world forward.  Relative to look, I am traveling 45 degrees to the right. I need r to be a rotation of 45 degrees right in this situation.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your formula is correct. It's possible you're applying the quaternions in the wrong order.

Comment: @Sneftel The order in which the quaternions are multiplied doesn't seem to make a difference.  I tried changing which one was conjugated, but that didn't work at all.

Comment: Can you give an example of a Q1 and Q2 that aren't producing the results you expect?

Comment: The quaternions are world space and view space in an XNA game.

Im using q1 as (0,0,0,1) and q2 as (-.3761814, .2987422, .05993626, .8750133)  the result I am getting is (.3761814, -.2987422, -.05993626, .8750133)  I am conjugating q2.  Sorry for the edits

Comment: Those results are correct. Applying that result, followed by Q2, will result in Q1.

Comment: It's not correct for my application though.  I am needing the opposite of the angle I am getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of the problem wasn't quite clear to me. I think that its probably best to derive the formula that you have found. Hopefully, this should allow you to understand (and visualize) why you might be getting the result that you are.

Given two quaternions, Q1 and Q2, the relative quaternion rotation **from Q1 to Q2** is:

```
Quaternion = relativeRotation = Q1^(-1) * Q2
```

Where `Q1^(-1)` denotes the inverse of Q1. You can think of this as applying the opposite rotation of Q1 to Q2. The result will be the relative rotation between the two. The inverse of a quaternion may be calculated by:

```
Q^(-1) = (Q*) / ||Q||^2
```

Where `Q*` denotes the conjugate of `Q`. I assume that you already know how to find the conjugate of a quaternion. Now, if `Q` is a **unit quaternion**, then both the norm and the square of the norm of `Q` is 1.0. Hence, we have:

```
Q^(-1) = Q*
```

This simplifies our formula to:

```
Quaternion relativeRotation = (Q1*) * Q2
```

Note that only unit quaternions represent rotations. However, since the Hamilton product of two unit quaternions is itself a unit quaternion, we don't need to normalize the result.

Now, from this relative quaternion, you can determine the angle (in radians):

```
float angle = 2.0f * acos(relativeRotation.w)
```

Here, `w` is the scalar component of the quaternion and `acos` is the arccosine trigonometric function. This angle is about the axis:

```
Vector3 axis = (relativeRotation.x, relativeRotation.y, relativeRotation.z)
```

Now, having found both the angle and the axis, you should be able to visualize the rotation.

Finally, as a side note, the Hamilton product (*) is not commutative. This means that `(Q1*) * Q2` does not necessarily equal `Q2 * (Q1*)`. Following the same derivation as above, the relative unit quaternion rotation from Q2 to Q1 can be calculated by:

```
relativeRotation = (Q2*) * Q1
```

Comment: `Qr = (Q1*) * Q2` seems to imply that the rotation equation is `Q2 = Q1 * Qr`, but as the OP mentioned, they are working with the (more common?) rotation equation: `Q2 = Qr * Q1`. In this case, shouldn't the relative rotation equation be `Qr = Q2 * (Q1*)`? Isn't that why the OP is getting reversed results?